# Detecting click on headphones

Tags: macos

When I plug in my headphones and listen to iTunes, pressing the remote will play/pause the music, and pressing on volume up and down will adjust the Mac's system volume.

I have an app that does media playback, and I want to respond to presses on the remote.  How can I do this? I don't see any NSEvents sent to my app when I press the remote.

Comment: It's been 9 months...ever figure it out?

Comment: This was never figured out.